# C# Regexp: How to extract $1, $2 variables from match

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, mono

Currently .NET uses their own nonstandard capturing group naming convention which is a dog.
I would like to enable the standard use of $1, $2 capture groups in C#.

Is their any way of doing it, or if not, is their any thirdparty regexp engines available for use, which do implement that kind of functionality.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a sample pattern, sample data, and the values you want to extract.

Comment: Seems there are very few third party commercial quality RegExp liraries available for .Net, so I guess I'll need to program around it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're looking for but it sounds like you want the ability to get the value for a given group in a matched regular expression.  This is definitely possible in C# (and .Net in general).

For example.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(a+)(\d+)");
var match = regex.Match("a42");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); // Prints a
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value); // Prints 42
```

While I don't use Mono regularly, I would be very surprised if this didn't work there as well.

Comment: I'm looking for a way in to implement the standard PCRE method of accessing named group as $0, $1, $2, $3 in C#

Answer (score 4):

According to 
[C# Regular Expressions](http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/news/csharp_0101.html), [Using Replacement Strings with Regex.Replace](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/regereplacementstrings.html), you can use the following code:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("  abra  ", @"^\s*(.*?)\s*$", "$1");
```